# AJAX POST not sending data instead it sends via GET method

Tags: jquery, ajax

[This is my jQuery function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2TF.jpg)

network output:

[image]

```js
function view_cet() {
  var action = "select";
  var fname = $("#fname1").val();
  var lname = $("#lname1").val();
  var bdate = $("#bdate1").val();
  var type = "C";

  if (fname != '' && lname != '' && bdate != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../include2/fetch-cet-sase.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      data: {
        action: action,
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname,
        bdate: bdate,
        type: type
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#output").html(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert('First name, Last name and Date of birth should not be empty. Pleas input a value.');
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your code somewhere where we can edit it, like https://jsfiddle.net/ or even here

Comment: Your JS looks fine. I'd guess the problem is caused because your function is called on submit of a form, which is set to send a GET request

Comment: @pyb here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/xcpc61ac/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how could I change it to POST method? I am really new to web programming. thanks

Comment: Well, you don't want to change it there as you're sending an AJAX request. You need to stop that form submission completely. This has been covered *a lot* on this site and other, if you take the time to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is solved by using Jquery.post()

```js
$.post( "../include2/fetch-cet-sase2.php",
{ fname: fname, lname: lname, bdate: bdate, reqtype: reqtype })
.done(function( data ) {
   $("#output").html(data);
   $("#btn-modal1").click();
});
```

Anyway thanks for the response :)